# Can't use using(s) Xamarin in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have Visual Studio Community and installed Xamarin in it. I updated xamarin.forms and SDK - JDK (not updated). Visual Studio can't detect `using`(s) or command(s).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solve for this error.
It's only a bug from visual studio 2017 community.
So need re install or repair visual studio and after programming spase will ok